# segmentation fault using pointers on array of strings

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

hi there i have this test code written that produces a segmentation fault on third iteration of while... using a debugger i saw the value of tokens[count] and it is correct but in the last iteration there is a segmentation fault,
str_split divide the string using ; as divisor(it works)
anybody can help?

```
   sportello[0].elenco_ris[0]=strdup("string;of;test");
   tokens=str_split(sportello[0].elenco_ris[0],';');

   int p=0;
   int count=0;
   int lungh=strlen("");
        while(p!=-1){
            lungh=strlen(tokens[count]);
            if(lungh!=0){
                printf("\nprinto: %s",tokens[count]);
                count++;
            }
            else p=-1;

        }
```

print: string
print: of

RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms

Comment: **unrelated observation**: You could just `if (tokens[count][0] != '\0')` instead of `lungh=strlen(tokens[count]); if(lungh!=0)`

Comment: you should use that debugger to step through your code, and identify the last line that executes before the segmentation fault happens

Comment: @SamIam yes and, the OP should post `str_split`.

Comment: a segmentation fault is almost always the result of you reading from or writing to unallocated memory.

Comment: What does `str_split` do? Does it return a pointer to a local variable maybe? And *where* do you get the crash? Did you try to run in a debugger?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the standard way to terminate arrays of pointers is to have a `NULL` pointer. Much like `argv` in the `main` function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I suspect the problem is the missing null-termination of a string, not an array.

Comment: Please provide the implementation of str_split.

Comment: `lungh=strlen(tokens[count]);` : last tokens is `NULL`. `while(tokens[count])puts(tokens[count++]);`

Comment: yeah i've seen it few seconds ago..i've posted the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i solved..the problem was what i thought...thaks to a comment by @Joachim Pileborg i've tried with this (NULL)... so thanks to you all

```
`int p=0;
       int count=0;
            while(p!=-1){
                if (tokens[count] != NULL){
                    printf("\nprinto: %s",tokens[count]);
                    count++;
                }
                else p=-1;

            }`
```

Answer (score -1):

the segmentation fault occures when the process execute strlen(tokens[count]) inside the IF at the last iteration..the return value would be 0(no string?) but instead seg fault...
probably in that location there isn't a string so this occures...how can i solve the problem? anyway this is str_split,it is the same(more or less) posted on this site somewhere,it works

```
char** str_split(char* a_str, char a_delim) {
char** result = 0;
size_t count = 0;
char* tmp = a_str;
char* last_comma = 0;
char delim[2];
delim[0] = a_delim;
delim[1] = 0;

/* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
while (*tmp) {
    if (a_delim == *tmp) {
        count++;
        last_comma = tmp;
    }
    tmp++;
}

/* Add space for trailing token. */
count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

/* Add space for terminating null string so caller
   knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
count++;

result = malloc(sizeof (char*) * count);

if (result) {
    size_t idx = 0;
    char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

    while (token) {
        assert(idx < count);
        *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(0, delim);
    }
    assert(idx == count - 1);
    *(result + idx) = 0;
}

return result;
```

}